# Tensorflow Tensorboard - should I follow the "smooth" value or the "Value"?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorboard, loss-function

I am using TF tensorboard to monitor the training progress for a model. I am getting a bit confused because I am seeing the two points that represent the validation loss value showing a different direction:

Time=13:30 Smoothed=18.33 Value=15.41..........
Time=13:45 Smoothed=17.76 Value=16.92

In this case, is the validation loss increasing or decreasing? thanks!

Comment: In general, two datapoints are not enough to draw a conclusion. You should watch the overall trend (e.g. is the cost increasing or decreasing). The smoothing is just a tool to help you to make a decision.

Comment: @DocDriven Sure I understand your comment. But even though following along the way, should I look at the trend of the real "Value", or look at the trend of the "Smoothed" value? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I cannot put figures in the comments, have a look at this graph.

[image: Smoothed curve]

If you watch the falling slope between x = 50 and x = 100, you will see that locally, the real values increase at some points (usually after downward spikes). So you could conclude that your function values are increasing. But at a larger scope you will see that the function values are decreasing. The smoothing helps you to get make the interpretation easier, but does not return exact values.

Coming back to the local example, it would give you the insight that the overall trend is a decreasing function, but it does not provide accurate loss values.